# How to handle edge case while trying to grab all digits including decimal between two chars using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am parsing a series of strings with various formats. The last edge case encountered has me stumped. I'm not a great regexer, believe me it was a challenge to get to this point.

Here are critical snippets from the strings I'm trying to parse. The second example is the current edge case I'm stuck on.

```
LBP824NW2-58.07789x43.0-207C72
LBP824WW1-77.6875 in. x 3.00 in. 24VDC
```

I am trying to grab all of the digits (including the decimal) that make up the width part of the dimension in the string (this would be the first number in the dimension). What works in every other case has been grabbing all digits from the "-" to the "x" using the following expression:

```
/-(\d+\.?\d+?)x\B/
```

However, this does not handle the cases that have inches included in the dimension. I thought about using "look-aheads" or "look-behinds", but I got confused. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: to be more clear, the output I'm looking for in the examples: 58.07789 and 77.6875

Comment: Sarah, you can edit your own question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RegEx can be told to look for "zero or one" of things, using `(...)?` syntax, so if your pattern already works but it gets confused by a new pattern that simply has "more string data embedded in what is otherwise the same pattern" you can add in zero-or-one checks and you should be good to go.

In this case, putting something like `(\s*in\.?\s*)?` in a few tactical places to either match "any number of spaces (including none) followed by `in` followed by an optional full stop followed by any number of spaces (including none)" or nothing should work.

That said, "I cannot change the formatting" is almost never an argument, because while you can't change the formatting, you can almost *always* change what parses it. RegEx might be adequate, but some code that checks for what kind of general patter it is, and then calls the appropriate function for tokenizing and inspecting that specific string pattern should be quite possible. Unless you've been hired to literally update some predefined CLi script that has a `grep` in it and you're not allowed to touch anything except for the pattern...

Comment: "but some code that checks for what kind of general pattern it is, and then calls the appropriate function for tokenizing and inspecting that specific string pattern should be quite possible." You're correct I could check the formatting of the string first and then handle each case differently. I'm working on possible solutions now using regex and then I'll try this method next. Thanks!

Comment: The nice thing about the latter approach is that it lets you clean up your input over time, too. Where regex are good at extraction, they're terrible for control flow, so if you identify patterns and the "route" based on those, you can also start doing things like notifying a secondary script of all the items that use the lesser-preferred format, so you can start getting those changed (by someone else =) to the preferred format.

Comment: That's something I was considering, I might even be able to write a secondary script that changes the formatting automatically. Thank you so much, this is a really helpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working solution using regex: `-(\d+\.?\d+?)(\s*in\.?\s*|x)`